# Fuzzy fonts in external monitor (Dell)

Tags: display, font

I recently switched to using Macbook Pro  **MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)** and it is running **MacOS High Sierra verison 10.13.6** . 
When I connect it to an external monitor (DELL U2414H) I notice that font display is grainy and fuzzy, as shown in this screenshot: [image: external monitor display]

I am connecting to the external monitor via HDMI. I see similar display when I connect to the external monitor using Displayport.

I searched through the forums and I tried below approaches:

- forcing to RGB mode as explained here: https://www.mathewinkson.com/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor.
- enabling/disabling _LCD Font Smoothing
- Setting various values to *AppleFontSmoothing* 
  (i.e. running the command `defaults write -g AppleFontSmoothing 2`)
- Restart the machine multiple times, resetting NVRAM and SMC settings
- Open the app in low resolution mode

But none of these steps helped, and fonts on my external display still appear fuzzy. I understand that in the external monitor the fonts can't appear as crisp they are on built in display. But I didn't expect the fonts to appear fuzzy on the external monitor. FWIW I was using a Macbook with out retina display prior to switching to this model, and didn't had any issues with display of fonts in the external monitor as I am currently facing.

Is there a solution to make the fonts to appear without any fuzziness apart from buying a new external monitor ?

Comment: Hi did you find already an answer to your issue? I am facing a similar problem.

Comment: No, I gave up and now used to fuzzy fonts on my Dell monitor.

Answer (score 3):

This is the [solution](https://gist.github.com/ejdyksen/8302862#gistcomment-2794614), It really worked for my 1920x1200 old monitor

Just follow the steps I made, because original receipt has some inaccuracies

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link isn't very helpful as it may no longer work in future. Instead, could you please edit your answer (there's an _edit_ link below it) to include a summary of the content you're linking to? This will make your answer more self-contained and help preserve it for other users in future.

Comment: Of course I can copy paste the whole ruby script file that solves the issue, but there is a whole branch with comments that are useful too. Is it ok?

Comment: It's fine, but something to remember for future reference as it's preferable to make your answer here as self-contained as possible (within reason, of course). It also means you're likely to get more rep as people prefer to upvote self-contained answers. :) Just for the record though, an edit wouldn't have to include *everything*, it can be something along the lines of: (1) Connect the display, (2) Download this script..., (3) Save the script to..., (4) Open Terminal, (5) Run these commands... etc etc. And of course you'd still cite and/or link to the solution. Thanks again for your answer! :)